# Directory Redirect to sub-folder with same name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect directory (.htaccess) to subdirectory with same name. I am getting redirection loop error.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /abc  http://www.example.com/lite/abc/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must delimit your pattern otherwise it will match `abc` everytime.

With `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc.*$ http://www.example.com/lite/abc/
```

Or with `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc.*$ /lite/abc/ [R=301,L]
```

Note: you'll need to clear your browser's cache before trying this code. Actually, your old rule is now in cache.

Comment: Hi Justin,

Thanks for prompt response. I tried that but it does not redirect now
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc$ /lite/abc/

Comment: What about my edited answer ? Also, please note that `mod-rewrite` solution will work (i did it because you included `mod-rewrite` tag in your question)

Comment: Minor point... the trailing `.*$` on the _pattern_ is not required here.